# Styled Components in React app with dynamic text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am working on a React app and using styled-components. So far things have gone well and I really like it but I am having some issues with making my styled-components as reuseable as I want them to be.

I feel like part of my problem is that I am still learning some about React and styled-components.

The app is built with react-boilerplate so my component markup is based off of their [example](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/master/docs/css#styled-components) on how to use styled-components. I am also using Material UI.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ListSubheader from 'material-ui/List/ListSubheader';

// styles for list subheader
const StyledListSubheade = styled(ListSubheader)`
  && {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px 16px 20px;
  }
`;

class ListSubheader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledListSubheader>Title</StyledListSubheader>
    );
  }
}

export default ListSubheader;
```

Pretty easy right? But what do I do when I want to change the text within `StyledListSubheader` in each component? What if I want to import `ListSubheader` in two different components and I want the text to be `Title` in one and `Example` in the other component? How do I dynamically change that text?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most easily done with the children prop of `ListSubHeader`:

```
class ListSubheader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StyledListSubheader>{this.props.children}</StyledListSubheader>
    );
  }
}
```

Which you can now user in other components as:

```
<ListSubheader>Whatever you like</ListSubheader>
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be working! Had a feeling it had something to do with `props`. I need to do a little more to fully understand how `props` works.